# Pause in android text to speech

Tags: android

I can pause and resume in text to speech by using below code but onRangeStart() values are discarded, i am highlighting text also while tts is speaking however when i resume, then onRangeStart() values fall back to 0th index.

HOW can i save onRangeStart() values?

```
int index;
int start;
int end;
String text;
String alltext;

public void getReady() {
     alltext = main_input.getText().toString() ;
     alltextlen = alltext.length();
     list.clear();
     int i;
     int i2 = 0;
  while(true) {
   i = alltextlen;
    if(i2 >= i - 1) {
     break;
  } 
String s = Character.toString().alltext.charAt(i2);
if(s.equals(".") {
list.add(i2);
i2++;
 } 
list.add(i - 1);
start = maininput.getSelectionStart();

while(i3 < list.size()) {
if(list.get(i3) >= start) {
 index = i3;
 break;
  } 
speak();
} 

private void speak() {
    if(index < list.size()) {
        end = list.get(index) + 1;
         text = allText.substring(start, end);
         start = end;
 texttospeech.speak(text, 0, null, "tts");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Where is the method you're talking about ?

Comment: It is method from texttospeech UtteranceProgressListener